# If $l$ is an integer such that $k \le l \le m$, show that there exists subspace $X$ of $V$ such that $U \subseteq X \subseteq W$ and $\dim(X)=l$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ such that $U \subseteq W, \dim(U)=k,$ dan $\dim(W)=m$
with $k \lt m$.

If $l$ is an integer such that $k \le l \le m$, show that there exists subspace $X$ of $V$ such that
$U \subseteq X \subseteq W$ and $\dim(X)=l$.

Any idea how to starting with? What theorem or properties or other in dimension of vector space could I use? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the basic ingredients:

- Every linearly independent set in a vector space can be extended to a basis (hint: $U$ is a subspace of $W$).
- Every subset of a linearly independent set is linearly independent, and is a basis for its span.

Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: Since $U$ is a subspace of $W$, then $U$ has a basis, say $X$. Since $X$ is a linearly independent set (in $U$ as well as in $W$), this $X$ is a subset of a basis, say $M$, for $W$. Thus, there exists a subspace $X$ of $V$ such that $U \subseteq X \subseteq W$. Whats, next? Anyway, am I true?

Comment: @user795084 I was thinking starting with a basis $\mathcal{B}$ for $U$, and extending to a basis $\mathcal{B}'$ for $W$. You can then start removing vectors from $B'$ as you like, so long as you don't touch the vectors in $\mathcal{B}$. By choosing the number of vectors to remove from $\mathcal{B}'$, you can form a vectors space of any dimension you wish, sandwiched between $U$ and $W$.

Comment: How to removing vectors from $B'$ without take vector in $B$?

Comment: @user795084 It's nothing fancy; you just do it. If $\mathcal{B} = \{v_1, \ldots, v_k\}$, and we extend to $\mathcal{B}' = \{v_1, \ldots, v_k, v_{k+1}, \ldots, v_m\}$, then we can just take, for example, $\mathcal{B}'' = \{v_1, \ldots, v_l\}$. I removed the final $m - l$ vectors from $\mathcal{B}'$, which definitely leaves the first $k$ vectors (i.e. $\mathcal{B}$), and gives us $l$ linearly independent vectors. We didn't have to remove the final $m - l$ vectors, just any $m - l$ vectors would do, so long as you leave $v_1, \ldots v_k$.

Comment: Where do "gives us $l$ linearly independent vectors" come from? From $B''$ isnt it?

Comment: We are taking vectors away from $B'$ until we have only $l$ left, and I'm calling the new linearly independent set $B''$. The way I've defined $B''$, it's clear that there are exactly $l$ vectors in it. Because $B'' \subseteq B'$ and $B'$ spans $W$, we know $\operatorname{span} B'' \subseteq W$. Because we have left $v_1, \ldots ,v_k$ in there, we know $U \subseteq \operatorname{span} B''$. So, $X = \operatorname{span} B''$ is exactly the kind of subspace we need.

Comment: Do you mean that "I removed the $m-k$ vectors and leaves $l$ vectors as in $B''$" ?

Comment: No, I did remove $m - l$ vectors, leaving $l$ out of the original $m$. If I were to remove $m - k$ vectors, I'd be left with $k$, i.e. the dimension of $U$, not $k$, the proposed dimension of $X$.

Comment: I have understood on your third argument. But, I still confusing in your second argument from the sentence "I removed ...".

Comment: I was just remarking about how $\{v_1, \ldots, v_l\}$ is not the only solution we could have come up with. So long as $l \neq m$, another solution would be $\{v_1, \ldots, v_{l-2},v_{l-1}, v_{l+1}\}$. We just need to make sure that a) $v_1, \ldots, v_k$ are still in there and b) there are exactly $l$ vectors in the set. But other than that, you can make whatever you like.

Comment: Ah... I see right now. Sorry for the inconvenient, Sir. Anyway, thanks a lot for your patiently and the answer, it very help me to understand this question.

Comment: You're welcome!